# How to make Hybris editorArea:panel resizable both vertically and horizontally?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to display a large amount of text in an "editorArea:panel" in the Backoffice. I want to be able to resize the panel using drag feature from UI both vertically and horizontally.

In my current confiugration in my *-backoffice-config.xml I have the below parameters. I tried specifying editor parameter (row - 20) which works as expected but cannot expand the panel past the 20 rows limit (makes sense). I also tried not including any parameters for "rows" but it renders what looks like a single long text box (NO scrolling at all either vertically or horizontally).

```
   <editor-parameter>

        <name>rows</name>

        <value>20</value>

    </editor-parameter>
```

Is there a way to make the panel both resizable via drag feature both vertically and horizontally?

Answer (score 1):

By default you have the Fluid mode enabled, making your Backoffice responsive. [See Fluid Mode in Editor Area Widget](https://help.hybris.com/1811/hcd/8c4080a3866910149512f5d251dea329.html#loio5cb1e1bc3fc543dea7e23b9d092b8d82).

You can only disable Fluid Mode per type using `viewMode=static`

```
<context merge-by="type" parent="Media" type="Document" component="editor-area">
<editorArea:editorArea xmlns:editorArea="http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/component/editorArea" viewMode="static"> 
</editorArea>  
...
...
...
</context>
```

You can also add a switch button to use static mode.

Comment: thank you. I will take a look at the documentation. But the drag feature I am hoping to keep for the panel and allow the user can expand width/height as desired. The panel in my case contains a large amount of text and be default I would like to display a specified dimension (e.g.  rows = 10).